Is it possible to pull number of shorts for channel?
In YouTube users can see number of Videos and number of Shorts posted for a channel.
I know how to pull number of Videos from the API (like $channel -> getStatistics() -> getVideoCount() - using official lib for php). But I'm not sure if is it's possible to identify number of Shorts via API.
I see it's possible to pull duration for individual videos, but I'm not sure if I can base at duration to calculate number of shorts or if there is more straightforward way. And just to clarify, Short is Video with duration <= 60 sec, it this correct?
Will appreciate help with linking me to proper documentation or any advice on my question.

By in YouTube users can see number of Videos and number of Shorts posted you mean that there is somehow on YouTube UI a text like This channel has posted N Shorts or you mean that users can notice N videos being Shorts?

I think so, cause we got the request to show next info from our end client: Published content, Shorts:nn, Videos: nnn

Use the details I've described in my question.
In resume, by using the YouTube Data API, you have to get the playlists of #shorts and get the number of videos on said playlist.
Example:

Channel_ID: UCbqEsRhXQI5KWYVr8mSWWWw
#Shorts Playlist_ID: UUSHbqEsRhXQI5KWYVr8mSWWWw <= This is the same CHANNEL_ID, but after replacing the first two characters from the CHANNEL_ID - in this case, the UC characters to UUSH at the beginning - Notice the highlighted characters.

Request:
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id,snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=UUSHbqEsRhXQI5KWYVr8mSWWWw&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN] Accept: application/json

Response:
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "Dq50F-zmW1AuTEP5t7UQK2lJi5Q",
  "items": [
    ... omitted for brevity
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 6, <= This is the total of videos on said playlist.
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  }
}

Try it here in the explore API demo.

Thanks Benjamin! Nice way, didn't know this hack about 'UUSH'.

@OksanaGritsjuk rememeber to accept the answer - more info here.
